# Check Billing and shipping info to be the same using Drupal commerce module?

Tags: commerce

I'm using the drupal commerce module and I also installed the [commmerce shipping module](http://drupal.org/project/commerce_shipping). Now in my cart I have the form to enter the Billing and Shipping information. So far so good, but I'd like to have the checkbox option to check something like: "Use the billing information for the shipping information". Then when checked I should be able to submit the form and the validation will skip the shipping information form.

Do I need to installed other modules to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No.

<del>I recently added this feature to the commerce shopping module (both 1.x and 2.x branch). It hasn't been widely tested yet though, but I am using it for a production site and haven't seen any problems.</del>

It's available for the 1.0 version <del>or the 2.x-dev version</del>.

This feature has been moved to Drupal Commerce in the 1.4 release (at the time of writing yet to be released), which means right now it's in Drupal commerce dev release and not in the 2.x-dev release.

The setting can be found under:
/admin/commerce/config/checkout/form/pane/customer_profile_billing

Comment: when you say commerce shopping module you mean the http://drupal.org/project/commerce module? If so, I see no 2.x-dev version. If I don't need another module where and how do I do the setting?

Comment: Forget my previous comment, you meant the commerce shipping module. But I still don't see where a how to the settings. I'd like to have the checkbox option to check something like: "Use the billing information for the shipping information"

Comment: The functionality is created as an addressfield plugin, so you need to enable it for the billing and shipping address.

Comment: Hi, I don't find this plugin, where should I check?

Comment: I don't find it... I've checked under admin/store/customer-profile/profile-type/manage-field and the I click the edit for the raw address... I'm using shipping 7.2. What can I do?

Comment: @SydBarrett Se my updated answer

Comment: Thanks googletorp but shipping 1 is not compatible with flat rate. Have you got any other solution?

Answer (score 0):

Probably a better solution now integrated into Commerce itself: http://drupal.org/node/1410022