# How to allow all commerce customers to use their billing address as their shipping address, in Commerce Shipping 2.X?

Tags: 7, commerce

Almost all shopping sites have a feature to allow customers to use their billing address as their shipping address, to save them typing it in twice in the very common case of a customer having the same shipping address as their billing address. This should be possible both for customers with accounts, and for anonymous customers.

Looking for this feature in Drupal Commerce, I find [some hacks suggeested in 2012](https://drupalcommerce.org/discussions/1049/shipping-same-billing), and a [long issue report](https://www.drupal.org/node/1243846) that seems to suggest this feature has been implemented.

However, the steps listed in that issue seem to be for the 1.X branch only, not the 2.X branch, and seem to no longer apply:

> For people who are a little lost like me, this is where you will find the settings:
>
> - store/customer-profiles/types/billing
> - store/customer-profiles/types/shipping
>
> Halfway down the page, under Format Handlers, you'll see a checkbox with the following text:
>
> "Copy billing address (required to be activated on billing profile along with the profile you want to copy the address on to. In order to work properly, the two addresses need to be on the same page.)."
>
> Check this on for both the billing and shipping profile types. Save both. I'd imagine you also need to make sure the other format handlers are identical between the two profile types--though I haven't tested it.

Those pages have moved, and I can't find any such checkbox in their new equivalent. [Likewise this related question is 1.X only](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/19191/check-billing-and-shipping-info-to-be-the-same-using-drupal-commerce-module).

How do we enable this common feature in the 2.X branch of Commerce Shipping?

Comment: Does anyone know similar feature in D8 Commerce?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Go to **Checkout Settings** (`admin/commerce/config/checkout`). Find **Shipping Information** pane and click `configure`.

You'll see setting for copying billing address right there (screen below)
[image]

Comment: I just found it and was starting to type up an answer, you beat me to it! I'll accept this as soon as the system allows me to (in 7 minutes, apparently)

Comment: Might be worth adding that if you want the opposite (users input billing address, which is then copied to shipping address), you can do it by doing the exact same thing but from the Billing Address configuration. [Here's a question in UX.SE about which is better in what cases](http://ux.stackexchange.com/questions/60846/why-ask-for-billing-address-first)